# Hide a menu on page load and need to populate on click of hyperlink

Tags: javascript, css, html, hide, show

I have pasted my code on http://jsfiddle.net/2YDPn/

Issue i face is I have a search page in a tab and results are displayed on click of search.

But when we click on result , it should open the details result in a new tab.

Initially i have hided the tab details. and onlick i am resetting the class and invoking the div class to show the content. But focus for the new tab is not set.

Please guide me on this issue. The code is pasted below as well

```
<%@ include file="common-includeCMTT.jsp"%>

<%
String language = request.getLocale().toString();
ResourceBundle bundle;

if (session.getAttribute("lang") != null) {
    language = (String)session.getAttribute("lang");
}
if (language.length()>2){
    language=language.substring(0,2);
}

Locale locale = new Locale(language);
session.setAttribute("LocaleObject", locale);
bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("MessageResources", locale);


String jsFileName = (language.equals("en")) ? "messages.js" : "messages_"+language+".js";


%>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="compo.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="common.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/sortable-tables.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tabs-2.js"></script> 


<title>Circuit Search Page</title>

<style type="text/css">
.toggle_class
{
display:none;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

          function check(fieldname)
          {
          if (/[^0-9A-Z]/gi.test(fieldname.value))
          {
          alert ("Please enter an alphanumeric value");
          fieldname.value = "";
          fieldname.focus();
          return false;
          }
          }

          function valForm(evt) {
          var form = document.circuitForm;
          if (form.usid.value != null && form.usid.value != "") {
          quickSearch('usid', form.usid.value); 
          }
          else{
          alert("Please enter a valid USID");
          }
          }

        function circuit() {
            document.getElementById("circuit_reference").style.display = "inline";
            document.getElementById("usid").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("router_name").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("euclid").style.display = "none";
        }
        function usid1() {
            document.getElementById("circuit_reference").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("usid").style.display = "inline";
            document.getElementById("router_name").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("euclid").style.display = "none";
        }
        function router() {
            document.getElementById("circuit_reference").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("usid").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("router_name").style.display = "inline";
            document.getElementById("euclid").style.display = "none";
        }
        function euclid1() {
            document.getElementById("circuit_reference").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("usid").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("router_name").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("euclid").style.display = "inline";
        }

 function popupDetailsEvent(submitEvent,value)
 {
    var url="circuitDetailsMain.do?event_type="+submitEvent+"&euclid="+value;
    var title="CIRCUIT_DETAILS";
    var submittedEvent = 'CIRCUIT_DETAILS_EVENT';
    if(submitEvent == submittedEvent)
        {   
  var newWindow = window.open(url, title, 'scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes, width=1000,height=700 ');
    if (window.focus) { newWindow.focus();  }
       //return false;
   }
 }

 function displayDetails(link)
 { 
    alert("hasgdhas"); 

    //window.open(link,'_self');
    document.getElementById("tab1").className = "";
    document.getElementById("tab1").className = "tabpanel-tabbar-item";
    document.getElementById("tab2").className = "";
    document.getElementById("tab2").className = "tabpanel-tabbar-item tab_active";
    //$('#content01').hide();
    $('#content02').show();
    //document.getElementById("content01").style.display="none";
    // document.getElementById("content02").style.display="block";
    // alert("tab1::::::::::"+document.getElementById("tab1").className);
    // alert("tab2::::::::::"+document.getElementById("tab2").className);

 }

</script>
<body class="COMPO">

    <html:form method="POST" action="circuitSearchMain">

     <div id="tabpanel-demo" class="tab_panel_2 clear">
      <ul id="tabpanel-liste" class="tab_menu clear">
                                    <li id="tab1" class="tabpanel-tabbar-item tab_active"><a href="#content01" class="tabpanel-tabbar-link">Search</a></li>
                                 <li id="tab2" class="tabpanel-tabbar-item toggle_class"><a href="#content02" class="tabpanel-tabbar-link">Details</a></li>
                               </ul>
        <div id="content01" class="tab_panel_content_2 " style="height: 450px; width: 990px;">

            <center>
            <br>
            <h2 class="title_n1_orange">Circuit Search</h2>
     <ul>
    <li>Please enter one of the search parameters.</li>
        </ul>   
                <br> <input name="radioButton" type="radio"
                value="Circuit_Reference" onclick="circuit();" /> Circuit Reference
            <input id="circuit_reference" onblur="check(this)" type="text" name="cctRef"
                style="display: none" /><span style="margin-right: 50px;"></span> <input
                name="radioButton" type="radio" value="USID" onclick="usid1();" />
            USID <input id="usid" onblur="check(this)" type="text" name="usid" style="display: none" /><span
                style="margin-right: 50px;"></span> <input name="radioButton"
                type="radio" value="Router_Name" onclick="router();" /> Router Name
            <input id="router_name" onblur="check(this)" type="text" name="routerName"
                style="display: none" /><span style="margin-right: 50px;"></span> <input
                name="radioButton" type="radio" value="Backbone_cct_reference"
                onclick="euclid1();" /> Backbone Circuit Reference <input
                id="euclid" onblur="check(this)" type="text" name="backboneCctRef" style="display: none" />
            <br> <br>

            <button type="button" class="button_action_large" title='Search'
                onclick="javascript:valForm('SEARCH_EVENT');">
                <span>Search</span>
            </button>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <button type="button" class="button_action_large" title='Reset'
                onclick="submitEvent('RESET_EVENT');">
                <span>Reset</span>
            </button>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <br> <br>


<logic:present name="circuitForm" property="circuitInfo">

<table class="sortable" id="id_unique" summary="Tables title" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<thead>
<tr >
<th scope="col" class="table_header first" abbr="EUCLID column (unsorted)"><a href="#">EUCLID</a></th>
<th scope="col" class="table_header" abbr="USID column (unsorted)"><a href="#">USID</a></th>
<th scope="col" class="table_header" abbr="ROUTER NAME column (unsorted)"><a href="#">ROUTER NAME</a></th>
<th scope="col" class="table_header" abbr="CIRCUIT ID column (unsorted)"><a href="#">CIRCUIT ID</a></th>
<th scope="col" class="table_header" abbr="CUSTOMER NAME column (unsorted)"><a href="#">CUSTOMER NAME</a></th>
<th scope="col" class="table_header" abbr="CUSTOMER CODE column (unsorted)"><a href="#">CUSTOMER CODE</a></th>
<th scope="col" class="table_header" abbr="CUSTOMER STATUS column (unsorted)"><a href="#">CUSTOMER STATUS</a></th>
<th scope="col" class="table_header" abbr="COUNTRY column (unsorted)"><a href="#">COUNTRY</a></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<logic:iterate id="result" name="circuitForm" property="circuitInfo"  type="com.equant.cmt.domain.business.Circuit">

<tr>
<%if(result.getEuclid()!=null && !result.getEuclid().equals("")){%>
<td class="quantity_data"><a href="#" onclick="displayDetails();"><bean:write name="result" property="euclid"/></a></td>
<%}else{%>
<td class="quantity_data">&nbsp;</td>
<%}%>
<%if(result.getUsid()!=null && !result.getUsid().equals("")){%>
<td class="quantity_data"><bean:write name="result" property="usid"/></td>
<%}else{%>
<td class="quantity_data">&nbsp;</td>
<%}%>
<%if(result.getRouterName()!=null && !result.getRouterName().equals("")){%>
<td class="quantity_data"><bean:write name="result" property="routerName"/></td>
<%}else{%>
<td class="quantity_data">&nbsp;</td>
<%}%>
<%if(result.getCircuitId()!=null && !result.getCircuitId().equals("")){%>
<td class="quantity_data"><bean:write name="result" property="circuitId"/></td>
<%}else{%>
<td class="quantity_data">&nbsp;</td>
<%}%>
<%if(result.getCountryName()!=null && !result.getCountryName().equals("")){%>
<td class="quantity_data"><bean:write name="result" property="customerName"/></td>
<%}else{%>
<td class="quantity_data">&nbsp;</td>
<%}%>
<%if(result.getCustomerCode()!=null && !result.getCustomerCode().equals("")){%>
<td class="quantity_data"><bean:write name="result" property="customerCode"/></td>
<%}else{%>
<td class="quantity_data">&nbsp;</td>
<%}%>
<%if(result.getCustomerStatus()!=null && !result.getCustomerStatus().equals("")){%>
<td class="quantity_data"><bean:write name="result" property="customerStatus"/></td>
<%}else{%>
<td class="quantity_data">&nbsp;</td>
<%}%>
<%if(result.getCountryName()!=null && !result.getCountryName().equals("")){%>
<td class="quantity_data"><bean:write name="result" property="countryName"/></td>
<%}else{%>
<td class="quantity_data">&nbsp;</td>
<%}%>
</tr>

</logic:iterate>
</tbody>
</table>
</logic:present>        
</center>
</div>

<div id="content02" class="tab_panel_content_2" style="height: 450px; width: 990px;">
hgvhjghj
</div>
</div>

</html:form>




</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some code snippets that may help point you in the right direction.

**HTML**

```
<div id=content02 style=display:none>
hgvhjghj
</div>

<a href=# onclick=showDetails()>Details</a>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function showDetails()
{
var content=$('#content02').html();
var newtab=window.open();
var newdoc=newtab.document;
newdoc.write(content);
newdoc.close();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. have to populate a jsp file in the div.